# MongoDB stopped the support for all 32 bits OS a while ago

Tags: php, node.js, django, mongodb, 32-bit

MongoDB stopped the support for all 32 bits OS a while ago because it's limited to about 2GB of RAM which is simply not enough to run something in production and it was too complicated / costly to support both 32 and 64 bits systems in the code.
I am learning MERN Stack Development and I don't have required specs computer (64bit), I learned NodeJs, React And also Express but Stucked at MongoDb because I don't have 64bit computer.I don't understand that how I continue. What technology replaces mongodb in this situation. It that PHP or Django(python).
And Here is my Code-

```
    const mongoose = require("mongoose");
    
    mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost:27017/test",{useNewUrlParser:true,useUnifiedTopology:true}).then(()=>{
        console.log("mongodb connected successfully!");
    }).catch((err)=>{
        console.log(err);
    });
```

Output-

```
    MongooseServerSelectionError: Server at localhost:27017 reports maximum wire version 3, but this version of the Node.js Driver requires at least 6 (MongoDB 3.6)
        at NativeConnection.Connection.openUri (C:\Users\MASTER\Documents\temp file\MERN With 6PP\mongoDB\node_modules\mongoose\lib\connection.js:824:32)
        at C:\Users\MASTER\Documents\temp file\MERN With 6PP\mongoDB\node_modules\mongoose\lib\index.js:381:10
        at C:\Users\MASTER\Documents\temp file\MERN With 6PP\mongoDB\node_modules\mongoose\lib\helpers\promiseOrCallback.js:41:5
        at new Promise (<anonymous>)
        at promiseOrCallback (C:\Users\MASTER\Documents\temp file\MERN With 6PP\mongoDB\node_modules\mongoose\lib\helpers\promiseOrCallback.js:40:10)
        at Mongoose._promiseOrCallback (C:\Users\MASTER\Documents\temp file\MERN With 6PP\mongoDB\node_modules\mongoose\lib\index.js:1234:10)
        at Mongoose.connect (C:\Users\MASTER\Documents\temp file\MERN With 6PP\mongoDB\node_modules\mongoose\lib\index.js:380:20)
        at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\MASTER\Documents\temp file\MERN With 6PP\mongoDB\index.js:3:10)
        at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1103:14)
        at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1155:10) {
      reason: TopologyDescription {
        type: 'Unknown',
        servers: Map(1) { 'localhost:27017' => [ServerDescription] },
        stale: false,
        compatible: true,
        heartbeatFrequencyMS: 10000,
        localThresholdMS: 15,
        setName: null,
        maxElectionId: null,
        maxSetVersion: null,
        commonWireVersion: 0,
        logicalSessionTimeoutMinutes: null
      },
      code: undefined
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

MongoDB is a NoSQL **database**. PHP on the other hand is a programming language and Django is a webframework written for python (also a programming language). When you want to find an alternativ to MongoDB you should look for other databases (in particular for NoSQL databases).
When your local machine is not able to run a new version of MongoDB, you have the following alternatives while still using MongoDB:

- Try out MongoDB Atlas, where you will be able to host a MongoDB cluster for free (https://www.mongodb.com/try). From your Node.js application you can still connect to it using credentials.
- Downgrade your MongoDB Driver to an earlier version so that these versions are compatible
- Of course you can switch to a 64-bit OS, but I assume it's not a suitable solution for you in this case.

Comment: Thankyou for your answer. I am using MongoDb Atlas now.